# SQL query help!! I'm trying to select the row that DOESN'T start with a number

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-like

I have 10,001 rows in my table, and all of the rows except one start with a number. I need to find this one row that doesn't start with a number, or even that doesn't contain a number.

So this is what I have:

```
Select col1 from table1 where col1 not like '?%'
```

Is this even close? I need to find the row that doesn't have a number...

Thanks!!

UPDATE: I am using a sqlite database

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT col1
  FROM table1 
 WHERE SUBSTR(col1, 1, 1) NOT BETWEEN 0 AND 9
```

### Reference:

- [core functions (incl SUBSTR)](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html)
- [LIKE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like)

Comment: Thanks for your help with getting this query figured out. I am using a gui based query browser called Base to get this query done, and when I run the above query, it throws an error that says: Near "BETWEEN": syntax error...any thoughts? Thanks again!

Comment: @Jerry: Fixed, typo from previous approach.

Comment: Just a minor point, not directly relevant with only 10k rows, but worth mentioning nevertheless, is that your solution makes the query predicate non-SARGable, eliminating any opportunity for the processor to use an index if one existed...   (but much simpler to type than my solution!)

Comment: I like my `ISNUMERIC` solution better than your `BETWEEN`, but I have the feeling that you're going to tell me that SQLite doesn't support it. :)

Comment: @Brad: Yes - `ISNUMERIC` is TSQL/SQL Server only :)  If it were available on SQLite, I'd have voted for you.

Answer (score 4):

On Sql Server,

```
Select * From table
Where col1 Like '[^0-9]%'
```

EDIT:   Don't know if there is an equivilent on SQLLIte,

but this will work...

```
Select * From table
Where col1 Not Like '0%' 
   And col1 Not Like '1%'
     ...
   And col1 Not Like '9%'
```

Comment: Yeah it seems like that would work, but it didnt...is there a sqlite alternative?

Comment: @OMG,  Yes, after some research I see you are correct... Like is part of the SQL-92 standard, but the pattern options are not..

Comment: @OMG,  did you misread it?  please check it out.. it works just fine.  it has to NOT be zero to nine all at the same time...  exactly what the op is trying to do.

Comment: @OMG,  to quote,  "I need to find this one row that `doesn't` start with a number".  It is your solution that does the opposite.

Comment: @OMG, Hah!! --- I, of course, have _never_ done that! You are a gentleman and a scholar, sir...

Answer (score 0):

There is a post in [code project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/SqlRegularExpressions.aspx) that allow you to use Regex with Ms SQL.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

@Dueber got me thinking, couldn't you just do this?

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE col1 > '9'
```

---

Grab the first character, see if it's numeric.

```
SELECT *
FROM   table1
WHERE  ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(col1,1,1)) = 0
```

[SUBSTRING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx)

[ISNUMERIC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx)

Comment: This is T-SQL, not SQLite

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way might be to just note that you're not using numbers; you're using strings that happen to have numbers in them. In this case, you can do

```
select * from table1 where col1 not between '0' and '9:';
```

(where the colon is the ASCII character after '9'; this way '9999999' won't be found).

It should be a lot less expensive than some of the other suggestions (e.g., checking the value of the first character).

Answer (score 0):

Use:

IsNumeric(Substring(col1,1,1))!=1

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).